# Telebot, How do I save a message from user into a variable?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm making a telegram bot which asks user different questions and I need to save their answers into variables.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['addproduct'])
def handle_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Price =")
```

Then a user answers and a program should save an answer into a variable price.

How do I save a message from the user into a variable?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: it will be possitive if you like my answer :) , finally you save variable into a database?

Comment: @segoitz-guibert yeah, thank u very much, i cannot like ur answer, cause don't have enough reputation to do this. The next_step_handler was something that i was looking for!

Comment: okay, no problem. In telegram there hare many groups about bots developing :) y have an example with variables and comments in spanish if u want it. https://github.com/boterostg/botBasicoGlitch y will create another proyect explaining in english.

Comment: @segoitz-guibert oh that's nice, thank u!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['addproduct'])
def handle_text(message):
    cid = message.chat.id
    msgPrice = bot.send_message(cid, 'Set your price:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msgPrice , step_Set_Price)

def step_Set_Price(message):
    cid = message.chat.id
    userPrice= message.text
```

## You can save "userPrice" variable in database or json/txt file  and then you have variable safe.